# opencv - apply median blur to part of image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a video frame from `cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4').read()`

My goal is to take that frame, and apply a `cv2.medianBlur(image, 7)` to certain areas of the frame defined by rectangles.

So far I only understand how to blur the entire frame with the `medianBlur` function.

Can someone explain how i would apply the blur only to certain portions of the frame? Or better yet, apply blurring to everything but a set of predefined rectangle coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose rectangular working regions of image ([SetImageROI](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#setimageroi)) one by one and apply blur to them.

Another approach: store original image, make blurred image, create mask image and do [cvCopy](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#copy) using original, blurred and mask

Comment: just tried setimageroi, but now it's crashing with a  "Segmentation fault: 11" error after processing about 1 second of a 3 second video. and i'm not really following you on the second option. the first one seems most straightforward. I'd really like to get that one working. any suggestions on that seg fault error?